# How to convert IntelliJ Idea run configuration into Eclipse launch file?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, run-configuration

I know that there is a plugin for IntelliJ Idea called "[Eclipser](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7153?pr=idea)" that converts Eclipse launch files into IntelliJ Idea run configurations. I would like to have the opposite conversion: from Idea run configuration to Eclipse launch file. Is there a plugin that does just that?

I've tried exporting Idea project to the Eclipse project format, but it does not export run configurations with it.